# Interface problem with disabled side bar?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, site-design, user-interface

I have disabled the side bay by checking the "Hide left navigation" button in my settings. However, when I do this the [Questions] [Tags] [Users] [Unanswered] navigation buttons are missing from where I would expect them to be (around the red circle below) along the top (although the [Ask Question] button is present). Because of this, getting to [All Questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions) seems to require typing in the URL as there is no obvious link.

[image: Snapshot]

I do not have this problem on other SE sites.

**Is this a Ux bug?**

If useful:

- I am using Firefox (v63) on different machines, and with different operating systems.
- I am using uBlock Origin, but am not blocking any elements on this page, and the behavior persists when I turn uBlock Origin off.
- I am using NoScript to block quantserve, and scorecardresearch, but behavior persists when I disable NoScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. The navigation is not supposed to show up where you've highlighted; nothing makes it show up there.

If you look in the top left you will find a hamburger menu beside the Stack Exchange logo. Click that. That is where you will find the navigation menu now.

The hamburger menu appears on phones and narrow windows *or* when you have chosen to hide left navigation. The “hide left navigation” option does not make navigation options appear along the top where you've highlighted, it makes them appear only in the hamburger menu.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that those Questions/Users/Tags/... tabs aren't in the red-circled area of OP's for *anyone* now, right, though they were for so many years. The new, responsive design has cleared out that area and moved them to left-nav for everyone. (Which users may then optionally hide away.)

Comment: Thank you, that was a perfect explanation. :) Although: the choice between "more clicks to use interface" or "more dead space" would not get my vote for user-friendly.

Comment: @Lexible Yeah there's definitely not universal love for the new sidebar, and the dead space is a common complaint. [I've requested adding some other common links to the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311456/152515) to make it less dead space & to make those links more available.

Comment: Why I've got a sympathetic ear, I am also no fan of four-clicks required to switch SE accounts. Grumble mumble shmumble... back in MY day... [growlix]... you damn kids!... we had to bang rocks together to get our ones and zeros . . . [something even less coherent here].

Comment: @Lexible (Depending in use-case there are alternatives to multiple accounts. If they’re for use on completely different SEs, and maybe ones that you don’t want to have associated, one account can use different names on different SEs, and hide specific SEs from being visible on the account. That makes for zero clicks.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That is precisely the use case I am in, but in order to switch users I need to (1) click the right talk/hamburger, (2) click log-out option, (3) click log-out button for my account, (4) click log-in button top, (5) click log in for my second account. Or am I missing something? The Ux designers are clearly missing the need for a "select account" menu.

Comment: @Lexible Stack Exchange is very much not set up to support multi-accounting, and in fact in many ways is hostile to it by design (whether accidentally or deliberately).

Comment: Yep! That's hostile Ux allright. (To be clear: I am talking about separate accounts for separate SEs). The making navigation options 1-click available for one layout (w/ left navbar), but penalizing those who opt for a different layout by demanding extra interface layers is likewise hostile Ux.

Comment: @Lexible It sounds like you don’t need separate accounts, just need to edit the profiles of one account to use different names on different SEs, then select the “sensitive” SEs to be Hidden from your overall profile. That’s what I do — I’m on Parenting, but unless you already know what name I use there, you probably can’t find it either through Parenting (unknown name), or through my profiles on other SEs (because it’s marked Hidden). If that setup works for you, then you can just have the extra account merged in, to collect rep and control of posts under one account.