# Something about the site layout changed, adding an unsightly line between the top bar and the site graphic

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design

There's a new light-colored line between the site graphic and the top bar that didn't used to be there and looks like it probably isn't supposed to be there.

### How it used to look:

[image: old image, without line]
(Ignore the annotations, it's from [this post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/role-playing-gamess-updated-site-theme-is-live/8393#8393).  Also ignore the change to the sidebar menu.)

### How it looks now:

[image: current screenshot of site, showing line]

It's happening on both Chrome and Edge; haven't tested other browsers.

Comment: [Its been like this since 2018](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8601/62294).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I don't think we're talking about the same thing, the image in your link doesn't show the problem I'm describing.  Editing a version with an arrow pointing to the line into the question.  *edit* Oh I see, the sidebar options moved to the hamburger menu between the two screenshots.  Separate change from what I'm talking about, as the updated image points out.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Top bar embiggened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389222)

Comment: @A_S00: For reference, the sidebar options are only in a hamburger menu for those who have enabled "Hide left navigation" in their [user preferences](/users/preferences/current).

Comment: I still see an unsightly white line above the banner on main, so I'm slightly confused about the [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Akixkisu does changing your zoom level cause it to disappear?  I think there were 2 related issues.  1) SE expanded the top bar by 4 pixels, and when doing so, accidentally added a border to the bar (this would persist even when you scrolled down).  That border was a bug, and has now been removed.  2) On my monitor, the expansion of the top bar resulted in a 1-pixel gap between the top bar and the header art at some zoom levels (but not others).  That is still present for me, but apparently not for V2Blast, and it also disappears for me if I change my zoom level.

Comment: @A_S00 Huh, that seems to be the exact reason, unsightly line on 125%, no hideous line on 110% zoom. Unfortunately, 110% is not sufficiently comfortable for my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Piper's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389234/335251) to the MSE post about this issue, [Top bar embiggened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389222/335251):

> The white horizontal line is a bug. GitHub was down yesterday when we went to push a fix out. Should go out today.
>
> The increased height (4px to be exact) is by design.

It looks like the white horizontal line bug has since been fixed.

Comment: They did make a change, but there's still a gap between the art and the top bar that didn't use to be there:  https://i.imgur.com/dQaLWwg.png

Is this a me-and-my-browser thing, or is everyone seeing this?

Comment: @A_S00: I'm not seeing that on RPG.SE. Try clearing your cache and reloading?

Comment: Cache clearing didn't change anything, but I did find that it's only there for me at certain zoom levels (it exists at 100%, but not 90% or 110%).  I hereby declare it a weird interaction among my browser, resolution, and site and I'm gonna take a deep breath and try not to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Digging into the CSS, it's caused by `border-bottom: var(--theme-topbar-bottom-border);` in the top bar code:

```
.s-topbar {
    min-width: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: var(--zi-navigation-fixed);
    background-color: var(--theme-topbar-background-color);
    height: var(--theme-topbar-height);
    display: flex;
    border-top: var(--theme-topbar-accent-border);
    border-bottom: var(--theme-topbar-bottom-border);
    position: relative;
    align-items: center
}
```

This is in the "[Shared](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=f577556dfd12)" CSS, so I think it's a network-wide change. Not sure that it gives a particular benefit though, even on sites where the banner is completely black.